# Мне нужно реализовать функционал при котором при выборе инпута значение его лейблов выводилось в отдельный блок Таких инпутов у меня 3 по два лейбла

Tags: reactjs, input, label

```
<dvi>  //место куда должны выводится значения лейблов
  <span><span/> //first_label
  <span><span/> //second-label 
<div/> 

<form action="">
      <div className="models">
        <input
          type="radio"
          id="Cpu1"
          className="lable_inp"
        />
        <label  className="first_label">
          i5-10400F
        </label>
        <label  className="second-label">
          80000 тг.
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="models">
        <input
          type="radio"
           id="Cpu2"
          className="lable_inp"
        />
        <label className="first_label">
          i5-11400F
        </label>
        <label  className="second-label">
          85000 тг.
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="models">
        <input type="radio"  id="Cpu3" className="lable_inp" />
        <label  className="first_label">
          i5-12400F
        </label>
        <label  className="second-label">
          100000 тг.
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Вы точно используете react? Покажите, как вы этот html рендерите и как у вас хранятся данные ваших элементов

Comment: данные нигде не хранятся, я только осваиваю реакт и пытаюсь реализовать написанный выше функционал и как показать как он рендерится я не знаю ибо это не html а jsx, я просто не стал весь код копировать а только саму суть

Comment: Покажите ту часть render, где вы выводите эти теги и расставляете значения. Так же интересует тип и формат хранения данных, которые вы расставляете. Вы же их в компоненте в какую то переменную помещаете. Поэтому да, нужен код jsx что бы можно было вам помочь. Его можно сократить и оставить только сутевую часть вопроса

Comment: я не понимаю как вам это показать. просто представим что это весь код который у меня есть и написан он внутри стандартного App.js внутри return () и все что выводится на странице это блок с инпутом и двумя лэйблами и блок в который нужно выводить значения лэйблов активного инпута

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С учетом того, что вы не понимаете, как добавить ваш код к вопросу, я пофантазировал и вот например решение, как при выборе того или иного элемента по radioButton отображать значения выбранного элемента.

> Используем события мыши. В вашем случае событие клика(click). В React.JS это onClick={}.
> При щелчке мыши по radioButton происходит запись в переменную view и за ним следует render компонента.

```
import './App.css';
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
// Тут эмулируем данные которые должны прийти
const radios = [];
// Создаем 5 товаров
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
  radios.push({
    id: `Cpu${i+1}`,
    name: `I${i+1}-10${i+2}00`,
    cost: 2 * (i+1) * 1000
  })
}

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]); // Данные
  const [view, setView] = useState({name: '', cost: ''}); // Выбрано
  // Функция записывем значения для отображения
  const fn = (id) => {
    setView(data[id]);
  }
  // Записываем данные в state
  useEffect(() => {
    setData([ ...radios ]);
  }, []);
  // Рендерим
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{width: 500}}>
      <form action="">
        {data.map((item, index) => {
          return <div className="models">
            <input
              type="radio"
              id={item.id}
              name={'r'}
              className="lable_inp"
              onClick={() => fn(index)}
            />
            <label  className="first_label">
              {item.name}
            </label>
            <label  className="second-label">
              {item.cost} тг.
            </label>
          </div>
        })}
      </form>
      </div>
      {/* Что было выбрано, отобразится здесь */}
      <div style={{width: 300, paddingLeft: 100}}>
        <span>{view.name}</span><br/>
        <span>{view.cost}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

События WEB элементов можно посмотреть на  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events
В react все эти события назначаются элементу как **on`<Event>`** в CamalCase формате

Comment: спасибо, благодаря тебе и код сократил и с проблемой разобрался)